# How I can pass 2 lists in items (LazyColumn)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have `LazyColumn` and I want to pass 2 lists in `items`, how I can do it

I want to do something like that if it is possible

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.85f)
) {
    items(cartItems,products) { cartItems,product ->
        CardProduct2(cartItems, product)
    }
}
```

Comment: What you wish to achieve is not clear. Why do you need 2 params in `items` if you wish to pass `cartItems` but not **carItem** to CardProduct2?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.** But you can try to do the following:

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
    items(max(cars.size, products.size)) { idx ->
        CardProduct(cars.getOrNull(idx), products.getOrNull(idx)) // Assume that your CardProduct composable are applying null values
    }
}
```

or better to merge this lists into one

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that if you are passing a list inside `CardProduct` is because you are using a `LazyColumn` inside to draw that list.

for that, just simply do this

```
Column {
    CardProduct2(cartItems, product)
}
```

Be aware of nesting `LazyColumns`, you will get a compilation error , it is better if you do the followin

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.85f)
) {
    items(cartItems, null) { cartItems ->
        CardProduct2(cartItems)
    }

     items(null, product) { product ->
        CardProduct2(product)
    }
}
```

Inside CardProduct2 do a simple null check to draw either one of the two , or if you need the two together just create `CardProduct3` that takes only product list. But inside CardProduct should not be any `LazyColumn` code, it should only be the card details itself

```
LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.85f)
    ) {
        items(cartItems) { cartItems ->
            CardProduct2(cartItems)
        }
    
         items(product) { product ->
            CardProduct3(product)
        }
    }
```

if you need `cartItems` and `product` data inside `CardProduct2` simply create an object that take `cartItems` and `product` parameters and pass that only one as your data